# How do I fix all the errors I am getting while trying to install google.colab with pip

Tags: python, pip, google-colaboratory

I've been trying to fix the errors for an hour now and every time I think I fix one, it creates more. If anyone knows how to fix the ones I currently have, that would be greatly appreciated

```
py -m pip install google.colab
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting google.colab
  Using cached google_colab-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-auth~=1.4.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached google_auth-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Collecting ipykernel~=4.6.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached ipykernel-4.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
Collecting ipython~=5.5.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached ipython-5.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (758 kB)
Collecting notebook~=5.2.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached notebook-5.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
Collecting six~=1.12.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pandas~=0.24.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached pandas-0.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-59snqcw7\pandas_1ef0b3e3a4804f6d82c5cd08d47e93ca\setup.py:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
        import pkg_resources
      C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      error in pandas setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          pytz >= 2011k
               ~~~~~~~^
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I've tried updating pip and I have 64 bit python 3.10.7 installed. I've also updated wheel and installed cmake. I run on windows 10. I have tried the pep517.

Comment: Please provide some system and version information

Comment: Have you tryed pip  this suggestion? install --use-pep517

Comment: Have you solved your issue? I think I have a similar one https://stackoverflow.com/q/77454929/5548026

Answer (score -6):

The error you're encountering is related to the installation of the google.colab package and its dependencies, specifically the pandas package. The error message suggests that there's a problem with the pandas package's setup script.

To resolve this issue, you can try the following steps:

1. Upgrade pip:

```
    python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

2. Try installing google.colab again with the --use-pep517 flag:

```
    python -m pip install --use-pep517 google.colab
```

The --use-pep517 flag tells pip to use PEP 517 for building packages, which can sometimes help with installation issues.

If the issue persists, you may also want to ensure that your Python environment is up to date, and that you have the necessary dependencies installed. Additionally, check if there are any issues with your Python installation or environment that might be causing this problem.

Comment: Hi ChatGPT-3.5-Turbo!