# Installing google-colab with anaconda and pip throws an error in pandas setup command

Tags: python, pandas, pip, google-colaboratory

I need to install google-colab and I keep having various issues with the task. Current version of python is 3.11.5 on Win11, pip version 23.3, conda is 23.10.0. I get the following error on my Anaconda Prompt.

```
Collecting google.colab
  Using cached google_colab-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting google-auth~=1.4.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached google_auth-1.4.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
Collecting ipykernel~=4.6.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached ipykernel-4.6.1-py3-none-any.whl (104 kB)
Collecting ipython~=5.5.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached ipython-5.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (758 kB)
Collecting notebook~=5.2.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached notebook-5.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (8.0 MB)
Collecting six~=1.12.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached six-1.12.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (10 kB)
Collecting pandas~=0.24.0 (from google.colab)
  Using cached pandas-0.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      <string>:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
      error in pandas setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          pytz >= 2011k
               ~~~~~~~^
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I had tried to downgrade python (to 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10) with no help, it would ask me to download Visual Studio C++, which after I did I would get an error : `'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.36.32532\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2`

I would downgrade setuptools, as I had seen some suggest online, that didn't help either.

I use the command `pip install google.colab --use-pep517`. If not I would also get:

```
  Using cached pandas-0.24.2.tar.gz (11.8 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [15 lines of output]
      C:\Users\theoP\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g1w_6le_\pandas_ca7c993ca7d04b0eb7b5f9b402a89232\setup.py:12: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
        import pkg_resources
      C:\Users\theoP\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py:84: _DeprecatedInstaller: setuptools.installer and fetch_build_eggs are deprecated.
      !!

              ********************************************************************************
              Requirements should be satisfied by a PEP 517 installer.
              If you are using pip, you can try `pip install --use-pep517`.
              ********************************************************************************

      !!
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      error in pandas setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          pytz >= 2011k
               ~~~~~~~^
      [end of output]
```

Has anybody seen anything like this before or have relevant resources? Personally haven't found anything exactly like this and everything I have tried from researching just crashes the install. Thanks.

Comment: What is your pip version?

Comment: @Goku pip version 23.3

Comment: @Goku, I downgraded pip to 22.2.2 and I got exactly the same message.

Comment: @Goku Thanks for your support. Downgraded to 23.1.1, still the exact same errors.

Comment: Oh... I wish I could find some solution for you. I found a similar question on SO but, the answer does not look helpful..... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77055059/how-do-i-fix-all-the-errors-i-am-getting-while-trying-to-install-google-colab-wi

Comment: Yes it does seem that it breaks during the reading of the pandas package, and although I have been trying to do several downgrades of several features to align everything, it just doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For me downgrading to python 3.7 worked. I think this is because the older version of pandas that google.colab uses is more compatible with that version.